# Do I need to service my water heater riser after the heater leaks?

Tags: water-heater

My water heater kicked it and started leaking into my garage. The house and heater are ~18 years old and I purchased the house in the last year so I don't know what the builders did for the riser. It appears to be a solid block, covered with some sort of drywall around the sides that got a bit crumbly around the edges when it got wet, and with corner pieces glued in to protect the edges.

Does anyone have any guesses on what's in my platform? I worry that the water heater leak water may have damaged it if it's not something like concrete, do I need to get it replaced or repaired before the plumber puts the new water heater on?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a waste to use that much cement to make a block for a water heater.  Best bet is to remove more of the drywall and take a peak inside.  Drywall not much more than decoration.

Comment: Add a pan and a drain pipe down to the ground to minimize water damage next time.

Comment: @crip659  gotta agree, rip off the drywall and see what's going on, I'd also remove the WH and if the top can be demo'd I see what was under that thing.

Comment: Depending if any water got under the top, you might need to remove the drywall anyway to dry out whatever is under it.

Comment: That corner piece looks like standard drywall corner bead (you'll have it on all the corners inside the house, too). The "glue" holding it on is standard drywall joint compound. Based on the amount of rust visible, though, this isn't the first time this stuff has been wet. Maybe it's just humidity in the air, but it's been rusting for a while now.

Comment: A picture of the entire area would be helpful if you want us to guess what's under there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the homes I have built the platform is actually made of scraps (short pieces) and covered with drywall to look better.

some we made a small storage space electric not gas, we had to have a drip tray under them it was a requirement and that may help you in the future.

If everything has dried out you can use Sheetrock mud (called joint compound) and put it back together.

If the Sheetrock is damaged it is easy to replace and possibly a good starter diy project as in the garage many times the Sheetrock is just painted not textured.
This could provide some experience with demo if needed and repair it is a easy DIY.